# Bean Instantiation Order

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, instantiation, cuba-platform

I have the following:

```
@Service(DropboxService.NAME)
public class DropboxServiceBean implements DropboxService {

    @Inject
    private CustomConfig customConfig;


    private final String ACCESS_TOKEN = customConfig.getDropboxAppToken();
    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

Does anyone know how I can get the values of the `customConfig.getDropboxAppToken();` to load first. I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'myApp_DropboxService' defined in URL
[jar:file:/E:/Cuba/myApp/deploy/tomcat/webapps/app-core/WEB-INF/lib/app-core-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/daryn/myApp/service/DropboxServiceBean.class]:
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
instantiate [com.daryn.myapp.service.DropboxServiceBean]: Constructor
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Current code I am trying

ERROR: Error creating bean with name 'ecosmart_BackupService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dropboxService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ecosmart_DropboxService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
@Service(DropboxService.NAME)
public class DropboxServiceBean implements DropboxService {

    @Inject
    private CustomConfig customConfig;


    private String ACCESS_TOKEN = "";
    DbxRequestConfig config;
    DbxClientV2 client;



    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("**************Running post construct");
        ACCESS_TOKEN = customConfig.getDropboxAppToken();
        config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
        client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
    }
```

Comment: Put that in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method. Injection can only take place after an object has been created.

Comment: I have updated with trying @postconstruct.  However, It still isn't working.  Presumably because the bean is being instantiated before the CustomConfig bean has on boot up...

Comment: You started with `myApp_DropboxService` and now you have a problem with `ecosmart_BackupService` so the problem is with the code in that class probably similar to this one.

Comment: That's not the problem...  I just changed the name.

Comment: Which line throws `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @Oleg  ACCESS_TOKEN = customConfig.getDropboxAppToken();
It will run if I comment this out.  I think it has something to do with the CustomConfig bean not being instantiated first - so it is null when this bean is instantiated.  I have been looking at some google posts about ATDependsOn but can't figure out how to do it...  Not sure if this is on the right track.

Comment: An `@Autowired` or `@Inject`, when used properly, cannot be `null`. Your application will fail to start with a message that an auto wired dependency cannot be found. Which leads me to believe you are creating instances yourself or haven't setup things properly.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Yes, I think it has something to do with the CustomConfig.  It CustomConfig is an interface which I built that extends an interface called config built into the platform - not really sure how it all works TBH.

Comment: I have posted my workaround solution as an answer.  Probably a bit ugly.  And still have no idea why the CustomConfig would be null @PostConstruct  :S !

Answer (score 1):

Spring injects fields only after the object was constructed and in your case `ACCESS_TOKEN` is initialized even before that.

You need to create a constructor and inject your bean in the constructor like so:

```
@Inject
public DropboxServiceBean(CustomConfig customConfig) {
  this.customConfig = customConfig;
  ACCESS_TOKEN = customConfig.getDropboxAppToken();
}
```

Comment: Getting this:
Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.daryn.ecosmart.service.DropboxServiceBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: accessToken

Comment: @Daryn Update your question with your current code.

Comment: @Daryn You need to move `new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);` inside the constructor.

Comment: Have posted it as a new answer below.  Am trying the @Postconstruct method as suggested above currently...

Comment: @Daryn like said, update your question with that. As an answer it will get deleted.

Comment: Have added to original question

Answer (score -1):

Well, after much mucking around, here is my great solution.  I have no idea why the CustomConfig would not intialise first...

```
@Service(DropboxService.NAME)
public class DropboxServiceBean implements DropboxService {        


    @Inject
    private CustomConfig customConfig;


    private String ACCESS_TOKEN = "";
    DbxRequestConfig config =new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
    DbxClientV2 client;

    public static boolean isInitiated = false;

    public void generateDbxClient(){
        ACCESS_TOKEN = customConfig.getDropboxAppToken();
        client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void uploadFile(FileDescriptorExt file, String path) {

        if(isInitiated==false){
            System.out.println("generating client");
            generateDbxClient();
            isInitiated=true;
        }
```